# Не запускается приложение на симуляторах в Xcode 12

Tags: xcode

Подскажите пожалуста, после обновления до **Xcode 12**, перестали запускаться симуляторы

Была ошибка **"in /Users/.../Pods/MobileVLCKit.framework/MobileVLCKit(VLCEmbeddedDialogProvider.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/.../Pods/MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.framework/MobileVLCKit' for architecture arm64"**

Я нашел в интернете решение, что нужно добавить **arm64** в **Excluded Architectures** параметром **Any iOS Simulator SDK**, что я и сделал

Затем такая же ошибка была только с архитектурой **i386**, я добавил в исключения и ее (в целях проекта и целях Pods)

Затем тоже самое с **x86_64**, добавил и ее

После этого вышла ошибка **'Build input file cannot be found '/Users/...Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SWSTB-asdgdfgbgfbg.../Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MYNAME.app/MYNAME'**

Я пробовал чистить **DerivedData**, но после этого либо ошибка повторялась

Как ее решить уже не знаю

На реальном устройстве запускается прекрасно, проблема только с симуляторами

Обновил **Xcode** до **12.01**, обновил cocoapods, обновил **mobilevlckit**, ошибка не пропадает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была с pod **MobileVLCKit**.

Разработчики pod добавили необходимые изменения для хорошей работы с **Xcode 12.x**

Нужно было обновить **MobileVLCKit** до **3.3.15** версии

У меня не обновлялось выше **3.3.13**, тогда я прописал команду `pod install --repo-update`. После этого репозиторий с pod обновился и удалось установить последнюю рабочую версию

Answer (score 1):

В `Build settings` пропишите:

```
ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH = YES;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

А легче - откатить на Xcode 11.

Comment: У меня стоят такие настройки.
Я скачал отдельно 11.7 версию и там тоже ошибка 'Build input file cannot be found '/Users/...Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SWSTB-asdgdfgbgfbg.../Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/MYNAME.app/MYNAME. Раньше ее не было, до обновления на 12 версию

Comment: @ДмитрийЧубаров , Cmd-Opt-Shift-K не помог?

Comment: Нет, clean часто делаю после каждой ошибки

Comment: @ДмитрийЧубаров из интереса создал пустой iOS проект и добавил pod 'MobileVLCKit'. Xcode 12.1 и на Xcode 12.2 заодно проверил. В Debug с ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES собралось без вопросов. В Release варианте, когда ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO собралось на симулятор после исключения только arm64.   Возможно у Вас что-то еще дополнительно сделано из-за чего могут эти проблемы быть? А по `Build input file cannot be found ` проверяли чтобы все на месте было: Info.plist, Compile sources?

Comment: В compile sources все swift файлы указаны, а как Info.plist нужно проверить я не знаю, но на вид вроде там нормально все) Я заметил, что у меня указаны в архитектурах valid architectures, возможно удалю их и попробую еще раз, но даже если это поможет, то скорее всего ошибка Build input file cannot be found не денется... Буду думать как ее исправить, сейчас она наверное самая важная. Пока пытался избавиться от других ошибок, заработал эту...